# Merged mining custom bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, namecoin, merged-mining

What are the core [changes to bitcoind](http://dot-bit.org/Merged_Mining#Getting_the_source_code_.28pool_operators_only.29) that allow one to [merge-mine](http://dot-bit.org/Merged_Mining)? Are there any new JSON-RPC commands that are enabled, or changes to the existing ones?

Comment: Just to clarify, the merged mining required no changes to the Bitcoin protocol.  Only miners that wanted to do merged mining needed to use a bitcoind with merged mining support.

Comment: @StephenGornick I know that there were no changes to the Bitcoin protocol, I was asking about the changes to bitcoind, the daemon that is used for generating getworks and the like.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is my merged mining implementation - not quite up to date](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=47779.0)

Answer (score 0):

None for the normal users. Allow writing to coinbase tx for solo merged miners and pools.

Some more info in addition to Stephen's Answer can be found here:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=48977.msg582955#msg582955